# Gettin json files from google cloud storage bucketangular

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I have translation service like this and I'm using assets/en_json or fr_json files but i want to move this files in cloud storage s3 bucket and i want to use in translation service how can i do that

````
    data: any = {};
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    use(lang: string): Promise<{}> {
        return new Promise<{}>((resolve, reject) => {
            lang = !lang ? localStorage.getItem('auth_user_language') : lang;
            const langPath = `assets/${lang || 'en_us'}.json`;
            this.http.get<{}>(langPath).subscribe(
                translation => {
                    this.data = Object.assign({}, translation || {});
                    resolve(this.data);
                },
                error => {
                    this.data = {};
                    resolve(this.data);
                }
            );
        });
    }
}```
````

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://dragonprogrammer.com/serve-angular-files-cloud-storage/ It is not s3 but I think it is the same direction

Answer (score 0):

I think this link could be helpful for you [Transfer files from GCS to Amazon S3](http://proanalyst.net/migrate-files-gcs-into-amazon-s3/). It is important to keep in mind that this is not an official documentation of Google and it can work or not.